# Transform a graph with ids to its index in Matlab

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have got a matrix Nx2 which contains edges from a graph. Indexes of the matrix correspond to ids of twitter users. Their relation is the retweeted status(if a user retweets another user). Totally in my graph there exists N retweeted relations. The number of users are M. I want to transform the ids of the graph from the initial twitter ids to 1:M ids. For example to replace the first id of the graph with 1(in every line and column that exists). I want to do so, without changing again the id which already have been changed. I tried to use a for-loop combined with find function in order to tranform ids to index. However what should I do in order to avoid changing items that already have been changed? I know that my code is wrong:

```
counter = 0;
for index = 1:length(grph)
   index1 =  find(grph(:,1) == grph(index,1));
   index2 =  find(grph(:,2) == grph(index,2));

   counter = counter+1;
   grph(index1,1)  = counter;
   counter = counter+1;
   grph(index2,2) = counter;
end
```

A little example which illustrates what I want, the following:

```
35113   45010   
5695    57711   
22880   33193   
22880   45010   
43914   35113
```

Desired output :

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
5 2
7 1
```

Comment: Can you try to explain this with an example?

Comment: Please format a bit your question, show the code you've tried, an actual output sample and a "desired" output sample. Otherwise it is difficult to understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty simple.  Use a combination of [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html).  Assuming your ID matrix in your example was stored in `A`:

```
[~,~,B] = unique(A.', 'stable');
C = reshape(B, [size(A,2) size(A,1)]).';
```

`A` would be the matrix of IDs while `C` is your desired output.  How this works is that `unique`'s third output would give you an array of unique IDs for each value that is encountered in `A`.  The reason why we need to **transpose** the result first is because MATLAB operates along the columns, and your result needs to operate along the rows.  Transposing the result effectively does this.  Also, you need to the `'stable'` flag so that we assign IDs in the order we encounter them.  Not doing `'stable'` will **sort** the values in `A` first, then assign the IDs.

`B` will inevitably become a column vector, and so we need to `reshape` this back into a matrix that is the same size as your input `A`.  Note that I need to reshape by the **transpose** of the result as `reshape` will operate among the columns.  Because we were operating along the rows, I need to reshape the matrix by its transpose, and then transpose that result to get your desired output.

Example use:

```
A = [35113   45010
5695    57711
22880   33193
22880   45010
43914   35113]; %// Matrix defined by you
[~,~,B] = unique(A.', 'stable');
C = reshape(B, [size(A,2) size(A,1)]).';

C =

     1     2
     3     4
     5     6
     5     2
     7     1
```

However, if sorting the IDs isn't required and you just want to have IDs per node ID, then you can just use `unique` as is without the `stable` flag.

Now, if you want to know which IDs from your graph got assigned to which IDs in the output matrix, just use the first output of `unique`:

```
[mapping, ~, B] = unique(A.', 'stable');
```

`mapping` will give you a list of all unique IDs that were encountered in your matrix.  Their position identifies what ID was used to assign them into `B`.  In other words, running this, we get:

```
mapping =

       35113
       45010
        5695
       57711
       22880
       33193
       43914
```

This means that ID 35113 in `A` gets mapped to 1 in `B`, ID 45010 in `A` gets mapped to 2 in `B` and so on.  As a more verbose illustration:

```
mappings = [(1:numel(mapping)).' mapping]

mappings =

           1       35113
           2       45010
           3        5695
           4       57711
           5       22880
           6       33193
           7       43914
```

Comment: Is it supposed with your approach the changes to happening vertically?

Comment: How can I keep the dictionary in order to be able to vice transform the matrix?

Comment: @JoseRamon - I'm sorry I don't understand your question.

Comment: How can I transform the new matrix with the first one? Is there a way to keep the relation of new ids with the old ones?

Comment: @JoseRamon - Yes, you can use the first output of `unique`.  I'll update my answer

Comment: See my example, is not exactly what I want. 22880 in line 3 and 4 have different id.

Comment: @JoseRamon - Ah I'm sorry.  I shouldn't take the transpose.  Let me change quickly

Comment: It is very silly question but why when using unique(A) it starts indexing from the second line?  [~,~,B] = unique(A);
C = reshape(B, size(A)) results to 
4 6;
1 7;
2 3;
2 6;
5 4;

Comment: @JoseRamon - I don't understand what you mean by "second line"?

Comment: @JoseRamon - That's because you forgot to use the `'stable'` flag.  If you don't do that, `unique` will **sort** the values, and then assign the IDs based on the sorted values.  If you read my post towards the end, there is a comment about that.

Comment: @JoseRamon - No problem :)  Glad I/we could help!

Answer (score 2):

I can't test right now, but this should do what you want:

```
[~, ~, kk] = unique(A.','stable');
result = reshape(kk, fliplr(size(A))).';
```

You need a recent enough Matlab version, so that [`unique`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) has the `'stable'` option.

If you have the Communications Toolbox, the second line could be replaced by

```
result = vec2mat(kk, size(A,2));
```

Comment: Wow 40 seconds apart lol.  I was actually just about to finish writing my answer when you posted.  I was debating on just scraping my answer all together, but I already invested so much time into it that I decided to post it.

Comment: @rayryeng Of course! And as usual your explanation is very good (+1 for that). I guess I'm too lazy for long explanations :-)

Comment: OH :) I like giving a bit more verbose explanations because it reteaches myself the concept.  To teach is to learn twice, right?!